# Identify first time visitor in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, say, I have the following table structure:

```
VisitorID  Date
Kristin    `2020-03-01`
Kristin    `2020-03-05`
Kristin    `2020-03-07`
PL         `2020-03-07`
Mithil     `2020-03-06`
Kristin    '2020-03-02`
```

The user Kristin visits the page for the first time on 1st March '20. I need a query such that we can flag this as 1. The next time Kristin visits, it should always be flagged 0. By flag I mean a new column that will indicate whether the user is a new visitor or not.

I tried using the Row_number in Snowflake but I'm not able to group by both date and visitor id.

```
select 
    date, 
    visitorid, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY visitorid asc) AS row_number 
from PRODUCT_VISITS_UNIQ
```

Comment: Tag `snowflake-schema` does not apply to this question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select visit_date, name,
IFF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY visit_date asc)) = 1, 'First Visit', '') as status
from
values ('2020-02-01','Hakan'),
('2020-02-01','Gokhan'),
('2020-02-02','Cenk'),
('2020-02-03','Gokhan'),
('2020-02-04','Cenk') p (visit_date, name)
```

Comment: Touchdown! This one is great!

Comment: the `ROW_NUMBER()` can also be replaced with a windowed MIN like `IFF(visit_date = min(visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY visit_date asc), 'First Visit', '')`